# Cmd module not cooperating with *args

Tags: python

I am trying to develop my Binance client with the Cmd module, however when I try to call a function from another file, it gives me an error.

This is for a Binance client i am writing.

### main.py

```py
def do_order(self, *args):
    """Places an order.\n
    Arguments in order:\n
    Buy or Sell option.\n
    Market or Limit option.\n
    The crypto symbol.\n
    The quantity of the order.\n
    The price of the order.\n"""



    market.Market.xch(*args[0], *args[1], *args[2], *args[3], *args[4])
```

### market.py

```py
class Market():
    #l = 0
    #m = 0
    #b = 0
    #s = 0

    def xch(self, xtype1, xtype2, xsymbol, xquantity, xprice ):

    print("Formulating the order...")

    #Time to sort the parameters

    #xtype1...
```

### Errors

```
[verl@verlpc Interface]$ python main.py
Loading Accounts...
CRYPTOANAYLISIS: PREDICTOR
> order 0 0 0 0 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 99, in <module>
    m.initAccounts()
  File "main.py", line 92, in initAccounts
    prompt.cmdloop('CRYPTOANAYLISIS: PREDICTOR')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/cmd.py", line 138, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/cmd.py", line 217, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "main.py", line 50, in do_order
    market.Market.xch(*args[0], *args[1], *args[2], *args[3], *args[4])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: try `market.Market.xch(*args)` or without `*` if you have to skip some elements `market.Market.xch(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4])`

Comment: you may have to also create instance of class - `m = market.Market()`  and then `m.xch(*args)`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create instance of this class

```
  m = market.Market()
```

And then you have use single `*args`

```
  m.xch(*args)
```

or many arguments but without `*`

```
  m.xch(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4])
```

---

Working example

```
class Market():
    def xch(self, xtype1, xtype2, xsymbol, xquantity, xprice ):
        print("Formulating the order...", xtype1, xtype2, xsymbol, xquantity, xprice)

args = [1,2,3,4,5]
m = Market()
m.xch(*args)
```

---

**EDIT:** you have to use `do_order(...)`

with `*` in definiton and when you run it

```
def do_order(*args):
    m = Market()
    m.xch(*args)    

args = [1,2,3,4,5]
do_order(*args)
```

or without `*` in both places

```
def do_order(args):
    m = Market()
    m.xch(*args)    

args = [1,2,3,4,5]
do_order(args)
```

Comment: i want to get the args from the Cmd prompt, like this 'order buy market BTCUSDT 0 0', but when using 'm = market.Market()' and 'm.xch(*args)' I get 'TypeError: xch() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'xtype2', 'xsymbol', 'xquantity', and 'xprice'

Comment: How do you run `def do_order(*args)` ? If you run with list then you have mistake and you don't need `*` in `do_order(*args)`.